# How to replace part of string with array items in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, replace, concatenation

I have patch of code as below:

```
var originalText = "111@gmail.com;333@gmail.com;555@gmail.com;";
var compareArr = ["111@gmail.com;222@gmail.com","333@gmail.com;444@gmail.com"];
var result = "";
```

Here, each item of originalText has to be compared with each items in array compareArr.
If first letter of item in an array is matched, then it should replace original string with item in array.

In above example, '111@gmail.com;;' is present in array, so '111@gmail.com;' would be replaced by '111@gmail.com;222@gmail.com;'.
Again, '333@gmail.com;' is present in array, so '333@gmail.com;' would be replaced by '333@gmail.com;444@gmail.com;'.

Final result that I want is '111@gmail.com;222@gmail.com;333@gmail.com;444@gmail.com;555@gmail.com;'

This is what I have tried so far which gives me only first string '111@gmail.com;222@gmail.com;' in output.

```
var originalText = "111@gmail.com;333@gmail.com;555@gmail.com;";
var compareArr = ["111@gmail.com;222@gmail.com","333@gmail.com;444@gmail.com"];
var result = "";

var arr1 = originalText.split(";");
for (x=0;x<arr1.length-1;x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<compareArr.length;y++)
    {
        var arr2 = compareArr[y].split(";");
        if(arr2[y] == arr1[x])
        {
            result += compareArr[y];
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

I expected output to be '111@gmail.com;222@gmail.com;333@gmail.com;444@gmail.com;555@gmail.com;' , but I am getting '111@gmail.com;222@gmail.com;;'.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that you are using the index in the comparison, and you're getting the wrong character. It is easier if I show you:

```
var originalText = "s;y;g;";
var compareArr = ["s;u;","y;o;"];
var result = "";

var arr1 = originalText.split(";");
for (x=0;x<arr1.length-1;x++) // Will run through s, y and g
{
    for(y=0;y<compareArr.length;y++) // For each character (s,y,g) will run through "s;u;","y;o;"
    {
        var arr2 = compareArr[y].split(";");
        if(arr2[y] == arr1[x])
        {
            result += compareArr[y];
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Let's examine

- When first `for` is **s** [x = 0]:

  - Second `for` is **s;u;** [y = 0];

    - arr2 = ['s', 'u']
    - Your if does `(arr2[0] == arr1[0])`, which is `(s == s)` - **It gets inside for**
  - Second `for` is **y;o;** [y = 1]

    - arr2 = ['y', 'o']
    - Your if does `(arr2[1] == arr1[0])`, which is `(o == s)` - **Doesn't get inside IF** ---> Here is the problem, as in your IF condition you're just using the same Y index, it will never use the "y" character from `compareArr[1]`.

So the solution is, in the if condition, always use the index 0, like `if (arr2[0] == arr1[x]`. But if you need to compare also the second letter, then you need to refactor your code a little.

In general, your code is a little bit confusing, I would advice using some techniques or some [Array.methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

In Your second loop `if` condition is wrong. You have to check with first element i.e `0` index, but you checked with `y`. It's causing prob.

```
var arr1 = originalText.split(";");
for (x=0;x<arr1.length-1;x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<compareArr.length;y++)
    {
        var arr2 = compareArr[y].split(";");
        if(arr2[0] == arr1[x])
        {
            result += compareArr[y]+';';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
var originalText = "111@gmail.com;333@gmail.com;555@gmail.com;";
var compareArr = ["111@gmail.com;222@gmail.com","333@gmail.com;444@gmail.com"];
var result = "";

var arr1 = originalText.split(";");
for (x=0;x<arr1.length-1;x++)
{
   for(y=0;y<compareArr.length;y++)
   {
      var arr2 = compareArr[y].split(";");
      if(arr2[0] == arr1[x])
      {
       result += compareArr[y];
   }
  else
        {
       var test = arr1[x];
       if(result.indexOf(test) != -1)
       {
        result;
       }
       else
       {
        result += ";" + test;
        }

        } 
     }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Result : 111@gmail.com;222@gmail.com;333@gmail.com333@gmail.com;444@gmail.com;555@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Gowri, 
As per your suggestion, I modified my code.
Also, I missed adding remaining string which I have added again.
Below is my final working code.

```
var originalText = "111@gmail.com;333@gmail.com;555@gmail.com;666@GMAIL.COM;";
var compareArr = ["111@gmail.com;222@gmail.com","333@gmail.com;444@gmail.com;"];
var result = "";
var resultArr = [];

var arr1 = originalText.split(";");
for (x=0;x<arr1.length-1;x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<compareArr.length;y++)
    {
        var arr2 = compareArr[y].split(";");
        if(arr2[0] == arr1[x])
        {
            result += compareArr[y];
        }
        else
        {
            result+=arr1[x] + ";";
        }
    }
}

function unique(list)
{
    var result = [];
    $.each(list, function(i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
    });
    return result;
}

resultArr = result.split(";");
resultArr = unique(resultArr);
resultArr = resultArr.filter(function(X){return X!==''});
console.log(resultArr);
```